# Using URL With Variables to Effect Code

Tags: php, url, optimization, using

I was wondering how you use ? (question marks) in your website to make it do different stuff based on the variable in the url.
like:
http://example.com/php/learn/kinder.php?level=$level
like what's that called, and how do you use it?
I assume with a switch statement
This is my code at the momment:

```
<php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","pass","db");
  //Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

$level = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT gradek FROM profiles");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Redirecting </title>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder.php?level=$level> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i'd have a switch... I know it's pointless. I just want to know for future reference.

So my question is:
how to redirect using php variable in html
How to use the ? to change the code.

I used bolli's code and this is what appears in the web page:

```
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder.php?level2=> </head> <body> </body> </html>
```

And it still doesn't redirect correctly

Comment: what is your question??? -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kinder.php place:

```
$level = $_REQUEST['level'];
echo $level;
```

And read about POST and GET request.
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Or do you mean how to place the variable in the URL?

Either do

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder.php?level=<?php echo $level;?>>
```

or

```
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://teachertechtutor.com/php/learn/kinder.php?level=".$level;
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Are you trying to get the variable and based on it, switch the page content?

You could do something like this?

```
<?php

//you could load header here
//include 'header.php';

/*
*Load content based on $_get parameter
*/

    // Get the $variable from the url after the level=
$page = (isset($_GET['level'])) ? $_GET['level'] : 'index';

//Check to see if the file exist
if (!file_exists($page . '.php'))
{
//echo "File does not exist" . $page;
}

switch ($page)
{
case 'test':
include('test.php');
break;

case 'test2':
include('test2.php');
break;

case 'test3':
include('test3.php');
break;

//Defualt start page
default:
include('index.php');

}

// You could load footer here
//include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: how would i use this with a switch? Just insert a switch with the variable in the url, right?

Comment: Yes you get the request with either $_GET['level'] or $_REQUEST['level]. And you could use it in a switch statement as well or if else or whatever you like.

Please try to explain better what you are doing, maybe we can help futher.